# jquery mobile and jquery.validation radio validation error message won't go away

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am attempting to use jquery.validate in a jquery mobile project to validate forms. This works fine for the most part, except for radio buttons. The validation appears to work initially, and display the error text about required fields, but if a radio button is selected the error message does not go away.

It seems to work fine for other input types such as 'text' as shown in the jsFiddle. Is this perhaps a conflict between the two libraries (jquery mobile and jquery.validate)? I've tried many combinations of versions of the two libraries with the same results.

jsFiddle:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkxtH/4/)

Comment: I think you have to `.bind` the error message to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

> http://jsfiddle.net/cfmitrah/vkxtH/9/